# Executing .bat from MySQL query

Tags: mysql

For reasons which are convoluted and irrelevant for this question, I'm working on a Windows server behind a client firewall in which I have limited access to the Task Scheduler. I have root level access of a MySQL database I am moderating there, and was wondering if I could possibly call .bat executables from within the MySQL event scheduler. Eliminating the need for Windows Task Scheduler.

I can't fully reside within the MySQL event scheduler as the executables I wish to run will be making calls to other MySQL instances on 'neighboring' servers.

Is this something someone may have attempted or solved before?

Comment: Don't use mysql for this. Create a separate program. You will find many uses for it.

Answer (score 0):

To run a .BAT file from a MySQL procedure, you would need to develop a [User Defined Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-udf.html) in C/C++, and install the compiled UDF on the MySQL host.

But if you don't have access to use the Task Scheduler, you might not have access to install a UDF either.

I don't recommend using the MySQL event scheduler for running .BAT files or any external programs. You risk crashing your MySQL Service, and it's a terrible security vulnerability too.

Use the MySQL event scheduler only for making scheduled changes to data in MySQL.